# building a query based on get variables returned from an ajax call

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have this piece of code which is kind of working but not properly as i want. I have a form which has two select boxes and when the user changes the value of each an ajax call is made and the page updates the records matching the options chosen.

This bit is working fine.

However when the user is filtering the records by changing the select options but wants to return to display all the records (so resetting the options) by selecting "all" in both select boxes, nothing is being displayed? I have a if query which i thought would of worked to set the value of $sql depending if $query is empty or not.

Here is my html/php page

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showUser() 
{ 
var users = document.getElementById('instructor').value;
var sex = document.getElementById('club').value;

  if (users=="" && sex=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
     return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","get-user.php?student_instructor="+users+"&club="+sex,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select name="student_instructor" id="instructor" onChange="showUser()">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="Clive Double">Clive Double</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>

<select name="club" id="club" onchange="showUser()">
<option value="">Male/Female:</option>
<option value="">All</option>
<option value="sennen">Sennen</option>
<option value="marazion">Marazion</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="txtHint">

<b>Person info will be listed here.</b>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my get user.php code

```
<?php
include_once("includes.php");
$count = "";
$query = "";
#print_r($_GET);
foreach($_GET as $field => $value)
{
#echo "field = ".$field."<br />value = ".$value."<br />";

if($value != "")
{

    if($count > 0)
    {
        $query .= " AND ";
    }

    $query .= $field." = '".$value."'";
    $count++;
}
}

//ORDER BY SQL TO GO HERE


$where  = '';

if( !empty ( $query ) ) 
{
$where = ' WHERE '  . $query;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_register".$where;
}
else
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_register";
}


#echo "<p>".$sql."</p>";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result); ?>

<div class='col-sm-12 day-heading'>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Forename</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">Surname</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">Club</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Instructor</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">Date</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">Age</div>         
</div>
</div>

<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
$id = $row['id'];
$firstname = $row['student_forename'];
$surname = $row['student_surname'];
$age = $row['student_age'];
$club = $row['club'];
$instructor = $row['student_instructor'];
$date = $row['date_awarded'];
$grade = $row['student_grade'];
if($i % 2 == 1)
{
    $math = "odd-row";
}
else
{
    $math = "even-row";
}?>

<div class="col-sm-12 <?php echo $math?>">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2"><?php echo $firstname?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><?php echo $surname?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><?php echo $club?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><?php echo $instructor?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><?php echo $date?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><?php echo $age?></div>           
    </div>
</div><?php
$i++;
}?>
```

i'm looking to essentially have a reset option when both select boxes are set to all then all records are displayed, at present non are.

this is the bit of code i thought would work but sadly not

```
if( !empty ( $query ) ) 
{
    $where = ' WHERE '  . $query;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_register".$where;
}
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_register";
}
```

Can anyone see what i've done wrong? probably something simple knowing me :D

Comment: Even if you get this working, it's *wide open* to **SQL injection**.  You may want to change the approach you're taking.

Comment: check the value of users in js while sending ajax, it might be going empty. At the PHP backend you have check for value i.e. users should not be empty.

Comment: hi @david yep definitely need to address the sql injection problems, will move on to that now that i have the other bit sorted :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the `$query` variable to '' inside the for loop every time.

```
include_once("includes.php");
$count = "";
$query = "";
print_r($_GET);
foreach($_GET as $field => $value)
{
    echo "field = ".$field."<br />value = ".$value."<br />";
    //$query = " WHERE ";  //Commented this.

    if($value != "")
    {

        if($count > 0)
        {
            $query .= " AND ";
        }

        $query .= $field." = ".$value;
        $count++;
    }
}

//Added a New Variable
$where  = '';
if( !empty ( $query ) ) {
    $where = ' WHERE '  . $query;
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_register".$where;
echo "<p>".$sql."</p>";
```

Comment: thanks for your help, its much appreciated! Any chance you can tell me how i would go about showing all the database records from the table without having the where clause? sounds like it should be easy but again im struggling :( I have updated my original post with the new code :) thank you!